# Function factory exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, factory

What must do: Show a mensage on console showing the message “[]: wow” and growl with the message “[] dog>]: grrrrr”
There´s something wrong on the function factory, but i don´t know what

```
const cachorro = {
    "nome": ["Zicao", "Mel", "Brutus", "Bob"],
    "raca": ["Viralata", "Yorkshire", "Chihuahua", "Labrador"],
    "tamanho": ["medio", "pequeno", "menor ainda", "grande"],
    "latido": function(i){
        cao = this.nome[i]
        let msg = ('${this.nome[])}: Au Au');
        return console.log(msg);
    },
    "id": function(i){
        console.log('
        Nome: ${this.nome[i]}
        Raça: ${this.raca[i]}
        Porte: ${this.tamanho[i]} 
        ')
    }
}

cachorro.latido(Number(prompt("Name of the dog?")));
```

Comment: I don't see a factory function (or function factory?) here.

Comment: The messages you say you want to show and not in your code so clearly they won't get printed, and you don't explain what the problem is. This is not your first StackOverflow question - please read the Help section on asking questions before posting another

Comment: One of the problems is that you are trying to use template expressions like `${variable}` but you are surrounding them with the wrong type of brackets

Answer (score 0):

The problem was brackets, now works just okay.
Here the code corrected:

```
"id": function(i){
    console.log(`
    Nome: ${this.nome[i]}
    Raça: ${this.raca[i]}
    Porte: ${this.tamanho[i]} 
    `)
}
```